# Test receiving from local host for socket programmiong in c under windows

Tags: c, sockets

Hi I'm new to socket programming. I'm currently writing c code for client, which is my computer, to send something to local host 127.0.0.1 and see if local host has got the request and anything back. I can already get connected to the local host but I don't know what command do I use to test if I can talk to the local host.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<winsock2.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET s;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char *message , server_reply[2000];
    int recv_size;


    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Initialised.\n");

    //Create a socket
    if((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket : %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Socket created.\n");
    //server.sin_addr.s_addr = 127.0.0.1; 
    //server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("74.125.224.72"); //google IP address
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); //local host IP
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    //server.sin_port = htons(80);//IIS port
    server.sin_port = htons(60441); //local port
    //server.sin_port = 80;

    //Connect to remote server
    if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        printf("connect error:%d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(s);
        WSACleanup();
        system("pause");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("Connected\n");

    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What kind of server is your client connecting to? You can't just blindly send commands to it without knowing what kind of commands it is actually expecting, what formatting they use, etc.

Comment: It looks good for something that doesn't actually communicate anything:(

Comment: What server is listening on 127.0.0.1:60441 ?  You must have some idea?

Comment: As I said, I've only done connection so far. And yes it's not communicating cause that's why I'm posting this question.

Comment: Again, you have to know what kind of server you are connecting to in order to communicate with it. If you just send random data to it, the server will either 1) ignore you, 2) disconnect you, 3) wait for you to send the right data, or 4) maybe crash altogether.  Rather than connect to some unknown server, why don't you create your own server for testing purposes?

Answer (score 0):

Once you get a connection, you can use `send` to send a message to the remote server and `recv` to get a response back.  Exactly what you send and what you expect to receive depend entirely on what service you're talking to.

EDIT:

As an example, suppose you're talking to a web server and you want to retrieve the main page.  You could do this:

```
char request[] = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 127.0.0.1\r\n\r\n";
size_t bytesSent = send(s, request, strlen(request), 0);
if (bytesSent == -1) {
    printf("Error sending: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    return 1;
}

char response[10000];
memset(response, 0, sizeof(response));
size_t bytesRead = recv(s, response, sizeof(response), 0);
if (bytesRead == -1) {
    printf("Error receiving: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    return 1;
}

printf("response from web server: %.*s\n", bytesRead, response);
```

Comment: Hi I'm talking to local host 127.0.0.1. My problem is that I don't know what I'm supposed to send to it so that I can receive. I can't send things to web server because I'm using intranet at company.

Comment: Umm. you are trying to send stuff to  server with unknown functionality using an unknown protocol?   You have little problem, then:(

Comment: OK, if it's only TCP, you can only send a byte stream.  Send something, 'Hello World!\n'.  That's it, that would satisfy your protocol.

Comment: So it looks like you're connecting to something on port 60441.  What's running on that port.

Comment: @rmtracy: TCP is just the transport to establish a connection. You need a protocol on top of the transport to establish a communication dialog back and forth.  You have the transport piece, but now you need the protocol piece, and that is not something anyone can help you with without knowing what protocol the server is expecting your client to use.

Comment: @rmtracy Did this answer your question?